# How to get text on datalist option with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i have datalist option and i want to get the text value and not the value, the picture below is the example, i want to get the Kuruha as the text and not the 1 value, how to get it properly ?

html code :

```
        <datalist id="in">
        <option value="1">Kuruha</option>
        <option value="2">Agencia</option>
        </datalist>
        <input list="in" id=int>
```

picture example

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the `change` eventListener as usual on your `input` element, and then access its `datalist`.

Once there, you can filter it with `find` to extract the selected option (if any), and finally get the text tusing `textContent`.

```js
document.getElementById('int').addEventListener('change', function() {
  let selectedOpt = Array.from(this.list.options).find(item => item.value == this.value);
  
  if (typeof selectedOpt == 'undefined') {
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = '';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = selectedOpt.textContent;
  }
});
```

```html
<datalist id="in">
   <option value="1">Kuruha</option>
   <option value="2">Agencia</option>
 </datalist>
<input list="in" id="int">

<div id="results"></div>
```